# How do I draw a spherical skullcap

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I draw a spherical skullcap

[image]

Comment: If you copy the code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417132/121799), you'll have an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \def\r{3}
    \def\H{1.5}
    \begin{scope}
    \clip 
    ({\r*cos(-90)},{\r*sin(-90)}) arc [start angle=-90,end
    angle=270,radius=\r];
    \shade[ball color=gray!15,opacity=0.5] (0,0) circle (\r);
    \shade[top color=blue!50!gray,bottom color=blue!20!white,opacity=0.6] 
 ({-\r},{-1.1*\r}) rectangle ++({2*\r},{0.1*\r+\H});
    \fill[blue!50] (0,{-\r+\H}) circle [x radius={sqrt(\r^2-(\r-\H)^2)},
    y radius={0.2*sqrt(\r^2-(\r-\H)^2)}];
    \end{scope}
    \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
    \draw[dashed,|<->|] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$R$} (10:\r);
    \draw[|<->|] (4,{-\r}) --
        node[fill=white,font=\footnotesize,inner ysep=2pt,inner xsep=0]{$h$}
        (4,{-\r+\H});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]