# How to draw and color a spherical cap of arbitrary radius at a given point in a sphere using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d

I was wondering if there was an easy way of drawing and coloring a spherical cap centred at a certain point in a sphere. I have seen relationed questions like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433465/how-do-i-draw-a-spherical-skullcap), but the spherical cap cannot be arbitrarily rotated as it distorts the figure.

I wanted to reproduce something like the figure bellow such that the point correspoding to the north pole can be arbitrary chosen. My problem is that I do not know how to make Tikz to color just the cap differently than the rest of the sphere.

[image: Spherical cap]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Using `rotate=⟨angle⟩` as `scope` option (eg. `\begin{scope}[rotate=30]`) in the linked example doesn't produce what you want ?